# Declaring a one dimensional array of 6 and showing a random value between 1-6 in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I need help with my program. I declared a one-dimensional array of 6 and I want to show random values between 1-6 in a text box

My question is how do I show values in my array in textbox1.text?

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ClickMyFirstClassButton()

   If FirstClass.Checked = True Then

        'This piece of code declares an array
        Dim Seats As Integer()

        'This is a One Dimensional Array
        ReDim Seats(6)

        TextBox1.Text = (String.Format("First Class is checked. The number of seats are : ", (Seats)))
        'ElseIf FirstClass.AutoCheck = True Then

        'MessageBox.Show("FirstClass is Auto checked")
    End If
End Sub
```

I messed around with my program and this is what I did.

Public Sub ClickMyFirstClassButton()

```
    If FirstClass.Checked = True Then

        'Dim Seats As Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
        Dim Seats(0 To 6) As Integer
        Seats(0) = 1
        Seats(1) = 2
        Seats(2) = 3
        Seats(3) = 4
        Seats(4) = 5
        Seats(5) = 6

        TextBox1.Text = (String.Format("First Class is checked. Your seat is : {0}", Seats(RandomNumber(Seats))))
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("First Class is checked. Your seat is : {0}", Seats(RandomNumber(Seats))))
        'ElseIf FirstClass.AutoCheck Then

        'MessageBox.Show("FirstClass is Auto checked")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to know how to display the values in my array in textbox.text.

Comment: In VB.Net, the subscript on the array definition is the last index. Since the first index is 0, `ReDim Seats(6)` sets the array to have **seven** elements. Also, any use of `ReDim` is a code smell... there's rarely a good reason to use it. Finally, the code sample lacks enough context to answer the question, because the array is still empty. What are you doing to populate it?

Comment: I am not sure you understand what you are asking. An Array is a collection, your array has 6 values that "Can" be stored against it (or 7 if VB.Net is Option base 0, I can't quite remember). When you redim you have changed the number of elements in your array to 6 and wiped out any values (although there were none in your example). Then in your textbox you are trying to bring back Seats the array but are not specifying which element (ie Seats(2) for element 2). What I "think" you want is to populate the array with values then return the value from a random element correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you currently have "(Seats)", replace it with string.join(", ", Seats) and see if you like those results.

(Though I admit I'm not sure what this has to do with random values, it should display the values in your array.)

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure as to why you are using an array in this way If you just want a number between 1 and 6, this will do what you want:

```
Public Sub ClickMyFirstClassButton()
   If FirstClass.Checked = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = (String.Format("First Class is checked. The number of seats are : " & CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 6)) + 1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Is this a learning exercise? If so I would be keen to see the question that has been asked of you as it doesn't make much sense to me currently.